# Find command if filename doesn't exists in directory

Tags: find

How I want to display the folder that do not have certain file. But the concern is, the file is same name but different cases.

Case study:
In tools directory, there are subdirectories that contain `readme`/`README` file and some of them does not have. For example

```
/toola/readme
/toolb/README
/toolc/ (does not have readme file)
```

I want find command to display only toolc folder by using this command.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 ! -name '*readme*' -o ! -name '*README*' | awk -F "/" '{print $$2}' | uniq
```

But it doesn't work. It display all file since `toola` doesn't have `README` and `toolb` doesn't have `readme`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `find` to look for files that do not exist. However, you may use `find` to look for directories, and then test whether the given filenames exists in those directories.

When using `find` to look for directories, make sure that you use `-type d`.  Then test each of the found directories for the files `README` and `readme`.

Assuming the following directory hierarchy for some top-directory `projects`:

```
projects/
|-- toola
|   |-- doc
|   |-- readme
|   `-- src
|-- toolb
|   |-- doc
|   `-- src
|-- toolc
|   |-- README
|   |-- doc
|   `-- src
`-- toold
    |-- doc
    `-- src
```

Using `find` to find the directories directly under `projects` that does not contain a `README` or `readme` file:

```
$ find projects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    ! -exec test -f {}/README ';' \
    ! -exec test -f {}/readme ';' -print
projects/toolb
projects/toold
```

Here, we find any directory directly under `projects` and then use the `test` utility to determine which one of the found directories do not contain either of the two files.

This is exactly equivalent of

```
find projects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -exec [ ! -f {}/README ] ';' \
    -exec [ ! -f {}/readme ] ';' -print
```

Another formulation of the above:

```
find projects -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ ! -f "$pathname/README" ] &&
           [ ! -f "$pathname/readme" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

Here, we let a small in-line shell script do the actual testing for the two files and print the pathname of the directories that does not contain either of them. The `find` utility acts like a "pathname generator" of pathnames to directories for the in-line script to iterate over.

In fact, if the directory structure is like this, we may choose to not use `find` at all:

```
for pathname in projects/*/; do
    if [ ! -f "$pathname/README" ] &&
       [ ! -f "$pathname/readme" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

Note the trailing slash in the `projects/*/` pattern. It's this that makes the pattern only match directories (or symbolic links to directories).

A difference between doing it this way and using `find` is that with the above shell loop, we will exclude hidden directories under `project` and will include symbolic links to directories.

In all cases, we iterate over the pathnames of directories, and we test for the non-existence of the two filenames.

The only caveat is that the `-f` test will also be true for a symbolic link to a regular file.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Thanks for using `-exec` for its intended use and not as a weaker `xargs`..

Comment: @pipe `xargs` has its uses, but we don't often need it.

Answer (score 4):

Given that I vote for the clear and elegant [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477417/315749) by Kusalananda, I add that this kind of tasks look like operating on sets. A pure `find` tool alone doesn't fit well. Indeed it has to bring external tools in by using `-exec`.

A different approach could be using a compare/diff tool. For instance, assuming you have access to GNU `find` and a shell supporting process substitution (e.g. `bash`), and that you have no newline characters in your paths:

```
comm -2 -3 <(find ./tool* -maxdepth 0 -type d | sort) \
<(find ./tool* -iname "readme" -printf "%H\n" | sort)
```

Where:

- `comm` compares two **sorted** files line by line; the options `-2` `-3` let it remove from its output results that are only in the second file or in both files.
- `-printf "%H\n"` lets `find` print only the starting point under which the file was found, followed by a new line (we have to match the `-maxdepth 0` option that defines the other list).

Tested with the tree:

```
$ find ./tool* -printf "%p %y\n" | sort
./toola d
./toola/doc d
./toola/readme f
./toola/src d
./toolb d
./toolb/doc d
./toolb/src d
./toolc d
./toolc/doc d
./toolc/README f
./toolc/src d
./toold d
./toold/doc d
./toold/doc/readme f
./toold/src d
```

The command above gives:

```
./toolb
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#i) for case insensitive matching

all_projects=(projects/*(-/))
typeset -aU projects_with_readme # -U for unique
projects_with_readme=(projects/*/(#i)readme(:h))
projects_without_readme=(${all_projects:|projects_with_readme})

echo Projects with READMEs:
printf ' - %s\n' $projects_with_readme
echo Projects without READMEs:
printf ' - %s\n' $projects_without_readme
```

You can change the `(#i)readme` to `(#i)*readme*` to account for files called `README.txt` or `000README`, or the `(:h)` to `(-.:h)` to only consider *readme* files that are *regular* after symlink resolution (exclude directories, broken links and other special types of files).

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, but there was too much to write as a comment. There are several things wrong with this command.

Firstly, your logic is wrong. You probably want `-a` instead of `-o`. Your command:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 ! -name '*readme*' -o ! -name '*README*'
```

will find files that (do not have `readme` in them) OR (do not have `README` in them). If you simply run your command, you will see that it returns all files in your tree. Hence, you could use

```
find . -maxdepth 2 ! -name '*readme*' -a ! -name '*README*'
```

Secondly, you probably don't even need this construct. If you have a read of `man find`, you can see that there is an option called `-iname`, which is a case-insensitive version of `-name`. Hence, you can do

```
find . -maxdepth 2 ! -iname '*readme*'
```

Finally, you can see that if you run these commands, it returns anything that doesn't have the string in its name. Hence, the parent directories, including `toola` and `toolb` will appear, because they don't have the string in their name. This is expected, because, if you look at the output, there is no `readme` or `README` in the line at all. That is just the file *within* the directory.

Comment: thanks Sparhawk. Actually I already tried those command, which are using '-a' and '-iname', it stil doesn't work

Comment: Yes, that is explained in the final paragraph.

Comment: This looks like it would match all other files though (`main.c`, for example)

Comment: @roaima True. (Hence the "partial answer" part.)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
find -type d -maxdepth 2 -not -name '*readme*' | awk -F "/" '{print $$2}' | uniq
```

Comment: Note that the user wants to find all directories that does _not_ contain a file called `readme` or `README`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` + `sed`

```bsh
find missing-foo 2>&1 > /dev/null  | sed 's@find: ‘\([^’]*\).*@\1@'
```

Find prints to stderr if the file doesn't exists. Swap `stdout`/`stderr` and filter with sed. Ugly and probably brittle, but works for me.